# Linq Query Timing Out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this query that uses the DBContext entities I created.

```
var referral = entities.StudentReferrals.Where(x => x.ReferralID == p && x.SchoolYear == year).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I remove `x.SchoolYear == year` the query works fine, but with it my query times out.  The opposite of what I would expect to happen, I would expect the more you narrow a query down via Where clause constraints the less likely it would time out.

SchoolYear is a field in the query and the query itself is valid, when I perform the query within SQL Studio Manager it returns results in less than a second.

My confusion is, why would adding a constraint to the Where clause cause a query to time out??

`x.SchoolYear` and `year` are both strings.

The full query is...

```
SELECT     [Extent1].[BirthDate] AS [BirthDate],     
    [Extent1].[LegalFirstName] AS [LegalFirstName],     
    [Extent1].[LegalLastName] AS [LegalLastName],     
    [Extent1].[PreferredFirstName] AS [PreferredFirstName],     
    [Extent1].[PreferredLastName] AS [PreferredLastName],     
    [Extent1].[StudentNumber] AS [StudentNumber],     
    [Extent1].[LegacyStudentNumber] AS [LegacyStudentNumber],     
    [Extent1].[TranscriptSchoolCode] AS [TranscriptSchoolCode],     
    [Extent1].[OEN] AS [OEN],     
    [Extent1].[StatusIndicator] AS [StatusIndicator],     
    [Extent1].[SchoolYear] AS [SchoolYear],     
    [Extent1].[ReferralID] AS [ReferralID],     
    [Extent1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID],     
    [Extent1].[Active] AS [Active],     
    [Extent1].[ServiceTypeID] AS [ServiceTypeID],     
    [Extent1].[IsSchoolActive] AS [IsSchoolActive],     
    [Extent1].[Principal] AS [Principal],     
    [Extent1].[SchoolName] AS [SchoolName],     
    [Extent1].[SchoolCode] AS [SchoolCode],     
    [Extent1].[NearNorthSchoolCode] AS [NearNorthSchoolCode],     
    [Extent1].[TranscriptSchoolPrincipal] AS [TranscriptSchoolPrincipal],     
    [Extent1].[TranscriptSchoolName] AS [TranscriptSchoolName],     
    [Extent1].[TranscriptNearNorthSchoolCode] AS [TranscriptNearNorthSchoolCode],     
    [Extent1].[GuardianFirstName] AS [GuardianFirstName],     
    [Extent1].[GuardianLastName] AS [GuardianLastName],     
    [Extent1].[AreaCode] AS [AreaCode],     
    [Extent1].[ContactNo] AS [ContactNo],     
    [Extent1].[ReferredByFirstName] AS [ReferredByFirstName],     
    [Extent1].[ReferredByLastName] AS [ReferredByLastName],     
    [Extent1].[ReferredDate] AS [ReferredDate],     
    [Extent1].[Reason] AS [Reason],     
    [Extent1].[gender] AS [gender],     
    [Extent1].[grade] AS [grade],     
    [Extent1].[HomeroomTeacher] AS [HomeroomTeacher],     
    [Extent1].[IntakeTeamMember] AS [IntakeTeamMember],     
    [Extent1].[IntakeMemberID] AS [IntakeMemberID]    
FROM (SELECT     [StudentReferrals].[BirthDate] AS [BirthDate],     
        [StudentReferrals].[LegalFirstName] AS [LegalFirstName],
        [StudentReferrals].[LegalLastName] AS [LegalLastName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[PreferredFirstName] AS [PreferredFirstName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[PreferredLastName] AS [PreferredLastName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[gender] AS [gender],     
        [StudentReferrals].[StudentNumber] AS [StudentNumber],     
        [StudentReferrals].[LegacyStudentNumber] AS [LegacyStudentNumber],     
        [StudentReferrals].[TranscriptSchoolCode] AS [TranscriptSchoolCode],     
        [StudentReferrals].[OEN] AS [OEN],     
        [StudentReferrals].[StatusIndicator] AS [StatusIndicator],     
        [StudentReferrals].[SchoolYear] AS [SchoolYear],     
        [StudentReferrals].[grade] AS [grade],     
        [StudentReferrals].[ReferralID] AS [ReferralID],     
        [StudentReferrals].[PersonID] AS [PersonID],     
        [StudentReferrals].[Active] AS [Active],     
        [StudentReferrals].[ServiceTypeID] AS [ServiceTypeID],     
        [StudentReferrals].[IsSchoolActive] AS [IsSchoolActive],     
        [StudentReferrals].[Principal] AS [Principal],     
        [StudentReferrals].[SchoolName] AS [SchoolName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[SchoolCode] AS [SchoolCode],     
        [StudentReferrals].[NearNorthSchoolCode] AS [NearNorthSchoolCode],     
        [StudentReferrals].[TranscriptSchoolPrincipal] AS [TranscriptSchoolPrincipal],     
        [StudentReferrals].[TranscriptSchoolName] AS [TranscriptSchoolName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[TranscriptNearNorthSchoolCode] AS [TranscriptNearNorthSchoolCode],     
        [StudentReferrals].[GuardianFirstName] AS [GuardianFirstName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[GuardianLastName] AS [GuardianLastName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[AreaCode] AS [AreaCode],     
        [StudentReferrals].[ContactNo] AS [ContactNo],     
        [StudentReferrals].[ReferredByFirstName] AS [ReferredByFirstName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[ReferredByLastName] AS [ReferredByLastName],     
        [StudentReferrals].[ReferredDate] AS [ReferredDate],     
        [StudentReferrals].[IntakeTeamMember] AS [IntakeTeamMember],     
        [StudentReferrals].[IntakeMemberID] AS [IntakeMemberID],     
        [StudentReferrals].[Reason] AS [Reason],     
        [StudentReferrals].[HomeroomTeacher] AS [HomeroomTeacher]    
        FROM [dbo].[StudentReferrals] AS [StudentReferrals]) AS [Extent1]    
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ReferralID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[SchoolYear] = @p__linq__1)
```

Here is the StudentReferral definition...

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT p.person_id AS PersonID, p.birth_date AS BirthDate, p.legal_first_name AS LegalFirstName, p.legal_surname AS LegalLastName, p.preferred_first_name AS PreferredFirstName, 
                         p.preferred_surname AS PreferredLastName, p.gender, p.student_no AS StudentNumber, p.legacy_student_number AS LegacyStudentNumber, p.transcript_school_code AS TranscriptSchoolCode, 
                         p.oen_number AS OEN, s.status_indicator_code AS StatusIndicator, s.school_year AS SchoolYear, s.grade, CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%', s.Grade) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN CAST(s.Grade AS int)
                          < 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END AS bit) AS IsElementary, t.SchoolName, t.SchoolCode, t.NearNorthSchoolCode, pg.person_id AS GuardianID, pg.legal_first_name AS GuardianFirstName, 
                         pg.legal_surname AS GuardianLastName, pt.area_code AS AreaCode, pt.phone_no AS ContactNo, pt.email_account AS Email
FROM            Trillium.dbo.persons AS p INNER JOIN
                         Trillium.dbo.student_registrations AS s ON s.person_id = p.person_id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Schools AS t ON t.SchoolCode = s.school_code INNER JOIN
                         NNDSB_AD_Routines.dbo.Students_Trillium_Guardians AS g ON s.person_id = g.student_person_id INNER JOIN
                         Trillium.dbo.persons AS pg ON g.contact_person_id = pg.person_id INNER JOIN
                         Trillium.dbo.person_telecom AS pt ON pg.person_id = pt.person_id
WHERE        (s.status_indicator_code IN ('Active', 'PreReg')) AND (pt.telecom_type_name = 'home')
GROUP BY p.person_id, p.birth_date, p.legal_first_name, p.legal_surname, p.preferred_first_name, p.preferred_surname, p.gender, p.student_no, p.legacy_student_number, p.transcript_school_code, p.oen_number, 
                         s.status_indicator_code, s.school_year, s.grade, CAST(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%', s.Grade) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN CAST(s.Grade AS int) < 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END AS bit), t.SchoolName, 
                         t.SchoolCode, t.NearNorthSchoolCode, pg.person_id, pg.legal_first_name, pg.legal_surname, pt.area_code, pt.phone_no, pt.email_account, g.primary_contact_priority
ORDER BY g.primary_contact_priority
```

Comment: first of all SchoolYear should be DateTime and it can be indexed a lot faster.  Second of all go into your database and put an index on the column SchoolYear and that should solve the problem

Comment: or I'm sorry, if it is just a year - then you should use an int

Comment: When you add more constraints you are going to have to iterate more records before you find one that satisfies them (assuming you are lacking sufficient indexes). How many records are in your DB?

Comment: One other thing - can you post the SQL that's being generated by EF for this query?

Comment: @Scott_Selby the SchoolYear can't be a datetime the format is '20152016' for this school year for example.  Also I can change the datatype or index it because it comes from a provincial database for student information that is maintained by a third party.

Comment: @mgrenier - given that this is actually a view you are querying, it would be very interesting to see what parameter types EF is choosing, especially for the second one, because if it's not the correct type, this could cause a problem. Also can you clarify if *all* of the results are returned in one second in SSMS , or does it just *start* returning results after one second - there is a difference. Showing the execution plan of the view might help too. Finally, can you confirm if there is an index covering Schools.SchoolYear?

Answer (score 1):

I can almost guarantee that the query that EF produces and the query you're executing in SSMS are not the exact same `SELECT` statement. You probably wrote something like what Stephen Byrne has in his answer, i.e.

```
SELECT * from StudentReferrals WHERE ReferallID=1 AND SchoolYear='2015'
```

Right off the bat this query doesn't have a `TOP` qualifier on it which your EF query probably will due to the presence of the `FirstOrDefault` call.

Your first step should be to use something like SQL Profiler and grab the actual query that EF is generating. It's possible that with that query the optimizer is choosing to do a table scan because of the type of query that is being generated.

This likely won't make any difference, but you could also try rewriting your query as:

```
var referral = entities.StudentReferrals.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ReferralID == p && x.SchoolYear == year);
```

As an example, when I write the following query against my database:

```
OrganizationalNodes.FirstOrDefault(on => on.Name == "Justice League")
```

EF generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    -- columns omitted for brevity
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
        -- columns omitted for brevity
        '0X0X' AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[OrganizationalItems] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[OrganizationalNodes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE N'Justice League' = [Extent1].[Name]
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head with redoing it to use `FirstOrDefault`...I think this could be the OP's issue

Comment: After posting this I compared the query I wrote with `OrganizationalNodes.Where(on => on.Name == "Justice League").FirstOrDefault()` and I got the same SQL generated. EF does a pretty good job of parsing the expression tree and ending up in the same place with different combinations and permutations of how you code the query on the C# side. I do still stand by the statement though that the query he's testing with and what EF generates are likely not the same.

Comment: I am using FirstOrDefault() which I am not really sure why that would affect this issue.  I only want the first record returned.  I believe I am using the exact query it generates, because what I did was set up a watch in my code and copy the generated code then pasted it into SSMS and it returns the results immediately.

Comment: As far as removing the FirstOrDefault() it does allow me to store the query in my referral variable but as soon as I attempt to access a record I get timed out again.

Comment: @mgrenier: `FirstOrDefault` changes the query. Notice in my above example the conditional is actually in a subquery with a `TOP` on it. Anything that changes the query *could* affect it. The way you solve a problem is by evaluating and testing each thing that could affect the outcome one at a time until you find the cause. I'm assuming that the `ReferralID` is not unique on its own. Is the combination of `ReferralID` and `SchoolYear` unique? If so, remove the `FirstOrDefault` as it's unnecessary, you'll only get one or zero objects returned anyway.

Comment: ReferralID is the primary key of a table but in the StudentRefferal view that I am querying it is not necessarily unique that is correct.  Combined they do create a unique record yes, but if I don't return the first record then my referral variable just stores the query.  Then when I attempt to get the first record elsewhere I run into the same issue.  Is there a better way I should be attempting to get the first record?

Comment: If you're expecting only a single object returned you should use `SingleOrDefault` rather than `FirstOrDefault`. Probably won't make a difference to your time-out problem but it will make the intent of the code more clear to the poor schmuck who has to maintain it in six months. Also, can you update your original question with the actual SELECT statement that you captured and are testing with?

Comment: No need to be condescending with the "poor schmuck" comment...is Single vs. First that hard to decipher?  Entire generated query is in question.

Comment: @mgrenier - you mentioned that StudentReferral was a view - is it actually a view, or a single table? If it's a view could we see the view definition?
Also I'm not sure Craig W was trying to be condescending;  "poor schmuck" is a normal tongue-in-cheek way to refer to anyone who has to maintain someone else's code - especially mine, I might add :)

Comment: it is a view yes, definition is up now

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer the question

> why would adding a constraint to the Where clause cause a query to time out

The most likely cause is that you have a lot of data in the table, but no index covers the `SchoolYear` column. Therefore when you include in in a `WHERE` clause, this causes a Table Scan (because every row has to be checked to see if it should be included or not in the result set)

If you use SQL Server Management Studio and write the query manually for e.g

```
SELECT * from StudentReferrals WHERE ReferallID=1 AND SchoolYear='2015'
```

And then include the actual Execution Plan (Query->Include Actual Estimation Plan) then you will get the execution breakdown which will show you clearly if there is a Table Scan involved. If there is, create an index to "cover" the columns involved and it should fix your issue.

#### Update

Another possible solution could be to run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to clear out any cached execution plans just in case for some reason SQL Server has picked something insane for whatever query is generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: I wonder why the result takes only about a second in SQL Server Management Studio though

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury yes, I missed that in the question. let me think about it

Comment: I don't know much about Linq internals, but could it be that the table scan is pulling every row into an entity instance in C#, to evaluate the predicate?

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury - I don't think so, If OP were calling ToList() *before* the Where clause that could explain but otherwise EF should just generate a `WHERE` clause in the SQL it emits, and it should also be parameterised for re-use.

Comment: I did the DBCC FREEPROCCACHE which did not seem to help anything unfortunately.